# Adding controls to panel dynamically in horizontal layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, panel

I have a table created for each user in my code behind file. I want to add each table to the panel so that all tables appear horizontally. The Table has just 1 coulmn and multiple rows. So each table should be added in the side of the previous table 
I have tried css style `float:left` but it is not working up.

Here is my code

**C# part:**

```
  foreach( DataRow dr in t.Rows )
  { 
       if(........)
       {    
           tdr.Width = "200px";
           row = new HtmlTableRow(); 
           cell = new HtmlTableCell();

           row = new HtmlTableRow(); 
           cell = new HtmlTableCell();
           cell.InnerText = doc;
           row.Cells.Add(cell);
           tdr.Rows.Add(row);
           row = new HtmlTableRow(); 
           cell = new HtmlTableCell();
           cell.InnerText = "No Timming";
           row.Cells.Add(cell);
           tdr.Rows.Add(row);
           row = new HtmlTableRow(); 
           cell = new HtmlTableCell();
           cell.InnerText = weekday[i];
           row.Cells.Add(cell);
           tdr.Rows.Add(row);
       }
       //dr_list is my panel name 
       //tdr is my table name 
       this.DR_list.Controls.Add(tdr);
   }
```

**CSS part:**

```
<style>
    .float-left
     {
        float: left;
     }
</style>
```

**ASP.NET part:**

```
<asp:Panel ID="DR_list" runat="server" Direction="LeftToRight" Height="227px" 
    HorizontalAlign="Left" ScrollBars="Auto" Wrap="False"  
    CssClass='float-left' Width="1103px" >
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are adding the css `float:left` to the parent container i.e. your Panel.

hence your markup becomes something like:

```
<div id="DR_list" class="float-left" >
    <table  width="200px">
     //table 1 markup
    </table>

    <table width="200px" >
     //table 2 markup
    </table>
</div>
```

hence it won't work for the inner children

you should add it to the individual tables i.e.

do it like this:

assuming your `tdr` is `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable`

```
 tdr.Attributes.Add("class", "float-left");
```

so that your final markup becomes like

```
<div id="DR_list"  >
    <table  width="200px" class="float-left" >
     //table 1 markup
    </table>

    <table width="200px"  class="float-left" >
     //table 2 markup
    </table>
</div>
```

so your actual code should look like

```
foreach( DataRow dr in t.Rows )
{ 
       if(........)
       {   
           tdr = new HtmlTable();
           tdr.Attributes.Add("class", "float-left"); 
           tdr.Width = "200px";

           row = new HtmlTableRow(); 
           cell = new HtmlTableCell();
           /////rest of the logic
       }
}
```

Comment: this is still not wrapping each table next to one another

Comment: it has to. right click on your page in the browser, and see view-source, examine the markup that got rendered.notice if your tables have class="float-left".

Comment: yes it has the mark up is 
        <div id="DR_list" dir="ltr" style="height:227px;width:1103px;overflow:auto;text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;">
 
            
        <table width="200px" class="float-left">
  <tr>
   <td>Nurses</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>No Timming</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Friday</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <table width="200px" class="float-left">
  <tr>
   <td>Midwife</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>No Timming</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Friday</td>
  </tr>
 </table>

Comment: see this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/h7Wah/). I simply copy pasted same markup tht you've given here. you might have some global css defined somewhere which is either setting the width of panel to be too low or some other obstruction.

Comment: Not sure if it was because it was a panel i was adding but i had to do it like so .Attributes.Add("style", "float:left;");  But you lead me to it so i upvoted ya even if OP will not accept it lol